# Power BI: Record Last Action for By Sequence ID (Resets by Each Customer ID)

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to return the last action name using a sequence ID. I must also repeat this for each customer ID within the formula using DAX. I also want to exclude "N/A" as a possible answer.

[image: Sample Data]

Regarding the desired output, it will probably be best calculated as a measure. Additionally, I can't segment by customer by simply placing "Customer ID" as the rows for a table. I need the measure to actually repeat the output for each customer ID so I can get three counts (annually, quarterly, and monthly).

Comment: Could you post the expected output? as a table perhaps

Comment: I wrote it in the last column as "Desired Output" I just merged the cells since it's probably going to need to be a measure.

Answer (score 0):

This measure should work:

```
=
VAR a =
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( Data[Sequence] ), Data[Action] <> "#N/A" )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( VALUES ( Data[Action] ),  Data[Sequence] = a )
```

[image]

Comment: I think this would have two issues (1) i cant use a table of customer IDs to get the result and (2) I need a count or sum. I'll be using a dimension that lists all three options in a treemap and then was hoping to add this measure to count them